# Float Variable Decimal Number Problems in Java, C++

Tags: java, c++

I know this may be basic but the problem is that I was experimenting with a small program to implicitly convert data types into the highest order by Java, C++ hierarchy and the results were interesting, for example:

```
public class idk
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        double a;
        int b = 4565;
        char c = 'z';
        byte d = 1;
        short e = 32;
        long f = 74539;
        float g = 478.68f;
        a = b+c+d+e+f+g;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Here the output came to be

```
79737.6796875
```

But it should have been

```
79737.68
```

and in C++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double a;
    int b = 4565;
    char c = 'z';
    short e = 32;
    long f = 74539;
    float g = 478.68f;
    a = b+c+d+e+f+g;
    
    if(a == 79736.6796875)
    cout<<a;

    return 0;
}
```

And it did print a, so the end is that the decimal numbers are being altered and if the float variable was changed to double, then all the problems vanish, why is that and what is the solution?

Comment: ***But it should have been*** No this is actually wrong. Some numbers are impossible to represent by the floating point hardware implementation. This calculator should help you understand this behavior and what is stored: [https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)

Comment: the calculator gives a very small error whereas my error are in 10^-2 orders, why?

Comment: Put `79737.68` into the calculator and see what value it returns.